# Exchange 2013 is failing its Readiness Checks for installation due to legacy Exchange 2000/2003 records

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, exchange-2007, exchange-2003, exchange-2013

We're in the process of upgrading our exchange 2007 to 2013, but after running the readiness checks, we're getting an error.

Error reads: "One or more servers in the existing organization are running Exchange 2000 Server or Exchange Server 2003.  Installation can't proceed until all Exchange 2000 or Exchange 2003 servers are removed"

[image]

We don't have any Exchange 2000 or 2003 servers, but legacy records seem to still linger.

Resolution attempts:

- ADSIEdit removal of CN=childsite-Domain and sub entries located in
  Administrative Groups/site/Microsoft Exchange/Services/Configuration
  referring to legacy Exchange 2003 server previously installed into
  the root via the child domain.
- Removed residual objects in Sites and
  Services

We need to know where the Readiness Checker is gathering the information from and how to clear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like the exchange server was ever decommissioned
Has it been removed completely from the AD? And the old Exchange server is no longer shown under Servers? Please refer to the section "Remove the Exchange Server 2003 server from Active Directory"

[How to remove Exchange Server 2003 from your computer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/833396) 
 Just making sure this part has been covered